# Warum ist "das Konklave" neutrum?

Tags: etymology, spelling

Aus aktuellem Anlass: "Das Konklave" hat einen sehr ungewöhnlichen Artikel. Die meisten Leute würden wohl sagen, dass es ihrem Sprachempfinden widerspricht. Mir fällt kein anderer Fall ein, wo ein eigentliches Nomen, das auf "e" endet, neutrum ist. Alle anderen solchen Wörter sind aus Adjektiven abgeleitet:

- das Runde, rund, etwas Rundes
- das Alte, alt, etwas Altes

Ich bin mir der Herkunft des Wortes, als neutrum aus dem Lateinischen, natürlich bewusst. Trotzdem möchte man es ja in Einklang mit dem restlichen Wortschatz bringen. Lässt sich in Analogie zu den obigen Beispielen ein Adjektiv "konklav" ableiten?

- das Konklave, konklav, etwas Konklaves, die konklave Versammlung, …

Das Konklave wäre also einfach das Ding, das konklav ist. Diese Herleitung entspricht zwar nicht der historischen Entstehung des Wortes, aber Volksetymologien und nachträgliche Umdeutungen von Wortherkünften, um dem Sprachempfinden zu entsprechen, sind ja nicht ganz unbekannt.

Wo wir dabei sind, gibt es einen Grund, warum man das Wort nicht einfach eindeutschen und den Artikel ändern darf? Es heißt ja auch "das Fenster", aber fenestra ist a-Deklination (femininum).

Comment: ich bezog mich in diesem Fall auf den Titel deiner Frage. weiterhin habe ich bereits in meiner antwort darauf hingewiesen, dass eine sinnvolle Ableitung auf Verb, bzw. Adjektiv de facto unmöglich ist, aus dem Grund, dass es als substantivierte Form entlehnt wurde und nicht in seiner Grundform

Comment: Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch heißt es tatsächlich wohl "die Konklave". Ein (nicht unbedingt gutes) Beispiel ist die deutsche Synchronization von StarCraft.

Comment: @Martin Womöglich auch wegen des Wortes `die Enklave`.

Comment: @user unknown: Gehabe kommt von haben, das Vermeidbare von vermeidbar, das Bare von bar (nackt, blank), usw.. Sind also alles Nomen die aus Adjektiven konstruiert wurden :-)

Comment: Ich möchte darauf hinweisen, dass es eine ganze Reihen von Substantiven gibt, die auf -e enden, neutrum sind und zumindest nicht erkennbar von einem Adjektiv hergeleitet sind: Gebäude, Gebirge, Gefälle, Gemälde, aber auch (und das beginnt nicht mit Ge-) Ende.

Comment: Meine Vermutung ist, dass das Wort dafür einfach nicht gebräuchlich genug ist. Ich habe es jedenfalls außerhalb des Kontextes der katholischen Kirchenpolitik bzw. Geschichte kaum gehört (Ausnahmen sind wohl sporadische Vorkommen in Fantasy & SciFi - Welten). Ich habe es selbst bisher auch eher als Eigennamen für genau dieses Gremium empfunden und wäre noch nie auf die Idee gekommen, es in einem anderen Zusammenhang zu verwenden.

Answer (score 9):

### Bedeutung und Etymologie

Das Wort **Konklav**e hat zwei Bedeutungen:

**1**
Zum einen ist ein Konklave jene Versammlung von Kardinälen, die aufgerufen ist, einen neuen Papst zu wählen. In dieser Bedeutung gibt es auch einen Plural für dieses Wort: Die Konklaven. Denn da die letzten 110 Päpste von Kardinalsversammlungen gewählt wurden, gab es auch schon 110 verschiedene Konklaven.

Das Wort in der oben beschriebenen Bedeutung hat seinen Ursprung aber in einem Homonym, das ein Singularetantum ist, also einem Wort, das nur in der Einzahl vorkommt, und somit keinen Plural kennt:

**2**
Das Konklave ist ein Bereich im Vatikan, in dem sich Kardinäle einschließen, wenn sie den Papst wählen. Diesen Bereich (die Sixtinische Kapelle mit einigen Nebenräumen) gibt es nur einmal auf der Welt, daher gibt es dafür keinen Plural.

Der deutsche Name dieses Bereichs stammt vom italienischen *conclave* ab, dieses Wort wiederum vom lateinischen *conclāve*, was *verschließbarer Raum* bedeutet. Denn *conclāve* ist zusammengesetzt aus der Vorsilbe *con-*, die vom Wort *cum* abstammt und auf Deutsch *mit* bedeutet, und dem Wort *clāvis*, was übersetzt *Schlüssel* oder *Riegel* heißt.

Das Konklave ist also wörtlich ein Bereich »mit Schlüssel«.

---

### grammatikalisches Geschlecht, historisch betrachtet

Rollen wir das Ganze nun in der historisch richtigen Reihenfolge auf, wobei wir besonders auf das Genus achten:

Das lateinische Ursprungswort *clāvis* ist weiblich. Durch das Hinzufügung der Vorsilbe *con-* wurde es notwendig, auch den Schluss von *-is* auf *-e* zu ändern. Sprachwissenschaftler nennen diesen Vorgang *Per­fek­tivie­rung*, und das hat nichts damit zu tun, dass hier *clāvis* im Ablativ verwendet würde. Das kann man zwar an mehreren Stellen im Internet lesen, ist aber nicht zutreffend.

Damit entstand das Wort *conclāve*, das nach den lateinischen Gepflogenheiten sächlich war. Es hat mehrere Bedeutungen, nämlich: der Verschluss, der verschlossene Behälter, der verschlossene Raum, der Stall, die Hundehütte, die verschlossene Kammer.

Als es jedoch mit genau denselben Bedeutungen als Teil der italienischen Sprache verwendet wurde, war es männlich: *il conclave*. Denn die italienische Sprache kennt nur zwei Genera, männlich und weiblich. Es gibt keine italienischen sächlichen Wörter. Eine Übernahme des lateinischen Geschlechts war also nicht möglich.

Den Einzug in die deutsche Sprache schaffte dieses Wort rund um das Jahr 1500 herum, also zu einer Zeit, als Latein schon lange eine tote Sprache war. Übernommen wurde also das männliche italienische *conclave*, nicht das lateinische sächliche *conclāve*. Dabei wurde das Wort an die Regeln der deutschen Sprache angepasst, das heißt:

1. Beide *c* werden durch *k* ersetzt (weil im Deutschen *c* nur als Teil von *ch*, *ck* und *sch* vorkommt)
2. Der erste Buchstabe wird großgeschrieben (weil das Wort ein Nomen ist)
3. Das Genus ist jetzt **weiblich** (weil das Wort auf *-e* endet)

Bei der Bildung des Geschlechts eines Lehnwortes ist es im Deutschen ohnehin meist egal, welches Geschlecht das Wort in der Ursprungssprache hatte.

### Richtig ist also eigentlich:

> Die Konklave

---

### Aber:

Obwohl es für die sächliche Variante »das Konklave« weder eine grammatikalische noch eine etymologische Begründung gibt, dachten viele neunmalkluge Herrschaften, das Wort stamme (direkt!) von einem sächlichen lateinischen Wort ab, dessen Ursprungsgenus man mit aller Gewalt auch ins Deutsche hinüberretten müsse.

Da diese Herren (es waren kaum Damen darunter) als gelehrt galten und hohes Ansehen besaßen, eiferten ihnen auch jene Mitmenschen nach, die sich ansonsten auf ihr natürliches, und obendrein richtiges, Sprachgefühl verlassen hätten.

Und so war es jahrhundertelang Mode, seinen gehobenen Bildungsstand unter anderem dadurch auszudrücken, dass man »das Konklave« sagte.

Und genau dieser Zustand dauert auch heute noch an.

Comment: Hast du Belege für "die" oder "der Konklave"? Alle deutsche Wörterbücher kennen nur "das Konklave".

Comment: Gibt es online einen Artikel oä. zur Perfektionierung in genanntem Sinne?

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Sorry, es sollte »Per­fek­tivie­rung« heißen. Ich habe es bereits korrigiert. Link1: http://universal_lexikon.deacademic.com/284086/Perfektivierung Link2: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfektiver_Aspekt

Answer (score 2):

Das Konklave ist der feststehende Ausdruck der Kardinalsversammlung zur Papstwahl.

Ursprung ist  *con claudere*, gemeinsam einschließen, was die Natur der Versammlung treffend wiedergibt (Kirchenlatein, kein klassisches Latein). Daher ist auch keine Ableitung auf ein deutsches Adjektiv möglich, wohl aber im Lateinischen (*clausus*, ver-/geschlossen).

Hier dient *con* als Präfix der Anzeige, dass nicht alleine eingeschlossen wird.
Der Term wurde fest in die deutsche Sprache übernommen (siehe [Lehnwort](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehnwort)).
Dadurch wird eine Ableitung fast unmöglich.

Comment: Ist das sicher, dass Konklave von _con claudere_ kommt? Könnte es sich nicht um ein bastardisiertes Lateinisch-Italienisch-Gemisch handeln: _cum clave_ --> _con la chiave_ --> Konklave?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel es kommt sowieso nicht aus dem Lateinischen sondern aus dem kirchenlatein, was ja ein "bastardisiertes latein-latein Gemisch" in sich ist. dennoch ist dieser Ursprung der wahrscheinlichste, wobei auch andere interpretationen existieren. u.a. auch cum clave, dieser ursprung ist jedoch aufgrund der wortbedeutung unwahrscheinlich

Comment: conclave ist nicht "Kirchenlatein" sondern gut klassisch.

Comment: @fdb belegen bitte... mein Lateiununterricht hat mir clavus / clavia immer als alleinstehendes substantiv vermittelt. Ich halte einen rückschluss auf klassisches latein für einen Trugschluss

Comment: Belege sind in jedem lateinischen Wörterbuch zu finden (ich habe unten die Stelle bei Georges kopiert).

Comment: »con claudere« ist aus 2 Gründen falsch: 1. »con« gibt es nur als Vorsilbe, nicht als eigenständiges Wort (das wäre nämlich »cum«). 2. »Konklave« stammt über einen italienischen Zwischenschritt vom lateinischen »conclave« ab, das man sich als Zusammensetzung von »cum clavis« (»mit Schlüssel«) vorstellen darf.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. "Mit Schlüssel" wäre "cum clave" (Ablativ), nicht "cum clavis".

Comment: @fdb und das Kirchenlatein schlägt wieder zu. Zur zeit als dieser Ausdruck geprägt wurde, konnten nur noch sehr wenige Gelehrte überhaupt noch korrekt deklinieren :(

Comment: Cicero konnte korrekt deklinieren.

Comment: @fdb richtig, nur dummerweise hat cicero fast 400 Jahre früher gelebt :(

Comment: ...und das Wort conclave mehrfach geschrieben.

Comment: @fdb was einer falschen Verwendung eines anderen Wortes in späterer Zeit keinen Abbruch tut. Du vergleichst Äpfel mit Birnen.

Answer (score 0):

"conclave" ist klassisches Latein und ist neutrum. Die Eintragung by Georges lautet:

conclāve, is, n. (con u. clavis), ein »Verschluß«, a) für Menschen, jedes verschließbare Gemach, Zimmer, insbes. bald Speisezimmer, bald Schlafgemach (dagegen cubiculum, Ruhezimmer), Cic. u.a.: in conclavi edito recubare, Nep.: cenatum, cubitum in idem conclave cum alqo ire, Cic.: conclave concĭdit, Cic.: huius in sedibus pro cubiculis stabula, pro conclavibus (Speisezimmer) popinae sunt, Cic. – b) für Tiere, der Behälter, Stall, Col. 8, 1, 3. – / Genet. Plur. conclavium, Vitr. 7, 9, 2. – / Nbf. conclāvium, ī, n., Virg. gramm. epit. 5. p. 46, 11 H., wovon conclaviorum,Vitr. 6, 3, 8.

Comment: Willkommen auf german.stackexchange! Deine Antwort enthält leider keine neue Info, denn dass es im Lateinischen neutrum ist, steht auch schon in der Frage.

Comment: Der Eintrag zu diesem lateinischen Wort ist interessant und verdient sicher in diesem Zusammenhang festgehalten zu werden. Leider hast du aber die Frage nicht beantwortet.

Comment: Der Antwort ist nur hinzuzufügen, dass sich lateinische Fremdwörter im deutschen, besonders jene im kirchlichen Bereich, meist nach dem Genus in der Originalsprache richten.