# Deutsche Substantive mit mehreren Genus (keine Fremdwörter)

Tags: noun, gender

Ich weiß, dass es bei Wörtern, die aus anderen Sprachen ins Deutsche übernommen werden, Prozesse gibt, die zu verschiedenen Genus für ein und dasselbe Substantiv führen können, oder – sofern nur ein Genus für sie eingetragen ist – deren Genus von deutschen Muttersprachlern als unrichtig empfunden wird. Vergleiche diese Fragen:

- [»Der Joghurt« vs. »Das Joghurt«](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37860/der-joghurt-vs-das-joghurt)
- [Warum ist "das Konklave" neutrum?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6147/warum-ist-das-konklave-neutrum/20260#20260)

Außerdem gibt es deutsche Wörter, die zwei Formen mit unterschiedlichen Genus haben.
Siehe:

- [Other words like “die Socke” / “der Socken”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23709/other-words-like-die-socke-der-socken)

Beide Phänomene (Fremdwörter / verschiedene Formen eines Substantivs) sind für diese Frage unerheblich.

Bei Substantiven, die für mich nicht offensichtlich eingedeutscht sind, war mir allerdings noch nicht aufgefallen, dass mehrere Genus vorliegen können.
Nun bin ich auf das Wort *Geschwulst* gestoßen und habe instinktiv gedacht, es müsse »**das** Geschwulst« heißen: für mich ein klarer Fall von Neutrum.
Und das passt auch zu der in Hubert Schölnasts Frage dargelegten These, das sächliche Geschlecht sei für Substantive aus Verben entstanden, die etwa mit der Silbe *ge* gebildet werden: in seinem Beispiel das *(Pferde-)Geschirr* von *anschirren*.

Nun wurde aber *die Geschwulst* geschrieben.
Der Duden bestätigt: [Neutrum und Femininum sind korrekt.](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Geschwulst)
Ein Maskulinum wird dort nicht erwähnt.

Das [Grimm’sche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG10914#XGG10914) hingegen kennt das Geschwulst zunächst nur als Femininum, später auch das Maskulinum und

> ferner als neutr. collectivbildung zu schwulst das geschwülst: als sich einiges geschwülst an seinem leibe ereugete.

Ich ging davon aus, dass ein Substantiv, dass nicht offensichtlich Fremdwort ist, nur *ein* Geschlecht hat.

Um den Fall des *Ge-* ganz rudimentär zu überprüfen, habe ich auf der Webseite des Dudens in die Suchmaske *Ge* eingegeben und nacheinander die Konsonanten ergänzt (*Geb*, *Gec*, *Ged*…): ohne dann *enter* zu drücken, sondern nur, um eine kleine Auswahl im Drop-Down-Menü zu sehen.

Alle Treffer, die mir so angezeigt wurden und die dem Bildungsmuster von *Geschirr*, *Gewächs* etc. entsprechen, waren Neutra.

Wie(-so) entstehen Ausnahmen wie *Geschwulst*, und gibt es viele davon?
Mir ist kein weiteres Beispiel eingefallen.

Comment: Andere Wörterbücher sind durchaus der Ansicht, dass für *Geschwulst* nur (f) richtig sei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warum kann ein und dasselbe Wort unterschiedliches Genus aufweisen? Sprachwandel und regionale Variation. Das Genus variiert dann nicht bei einem Sprecher, sondern zwischen Gruppen von Sprechern.

Sprachwandel vollzieht sich nicht schlagartig, sondern so, daß Formen eine Weile miteinander in Konkurrenz stehen, bis sich eine durchsetzt. Man sieht dies am erwähnten Beispiel *Socke* f.: Früher gab es nur *Sock* m., woraus *Socke* m. wurde. Eine Zeitlang haben dann maskuline und feminine Formen nebeneinander existiert, aber am Ende gewann die feminine Form.

(Ein analoges Beispiel zu Substantiven mit mehreren Genera wie *Geschwulst* wären vielleicht Verben, bei denen zurzeit noch starke und schwache Formen koexistieren; z.B. *hauen*, *stieben*.)

Sind deverbale Nomen mit *Ge-* immer neutral? Nein!

> *Maskulin:*
> Gedanke
> Gefährte
> Genuß
> Geruch
> Gewinn
>
> *Feminin:*
> Geburt
> Gebühr
> Geduld
> Gefahr
> Geschichte
> Gestalt
>
> *Nomen, deren Genus sich gewandelt hat:*
> Gebärde (f., aber ehemals auch n.)
> Gebauer (n., auch m.)
> Gehalt (ursprünglich m., dann Aufspaltung: m. ist *Inhalt*, n. *Bezahlung*)
> Gesang (m., aber ehemals n.)
> Gesuch (n., aber ehemals m.)

In der Duden-Grammatik (8. Aufl.) findet sich unter §345 eine Tabelle mit Nomen mit schwankendem Genus. Darunter zum Beispiel:

> Abscheu m./f.
> Begehr m./n.
> Bereich m. (selten n.)
> Dotter m. (selten n.)
> Teil (Aufspaltung: m. *Anteil*, n. *Ding, Sache*)
> Kehricht n. (auch m.)
> Knäuel m./n.

Comment: Danke. Zumindest scheint es nicht viele Substantive mit mehreren Genera zu geben. Ich vermute, es war eine Tendenz im englischen Sprachgebrauch, dass die Genera konkurrierten und sich langsam *it* für alle Substantive durchsetzte? Zum 2. Teil der Antwort: Es gibt ja doch sehr viele Beispiele von *Ge-*-Wörtern, die nicht N. sind (da habe ich sehr schlecht gesucht).

Comment: Es ist schwer, nach Nomen mit mehreren Genera zu suchen. Aber Dialektsprecher kennen sicherlich das Phänomen, daß manche Nomen im Dialekt ein anderes Genus haben (*der Butter auf das Teller*).

Comment: Der "Klassiker" ist, glaub ich _der Butter_ (schwäbisch) / _die Butter_ (Standarddeutsch).

Answer (score 3):

Ich versuche die Frage mal breiter (nicht nur auf "Ge-") zu beantworten:

Der deutsche Sprachraum ist groß - Natürlich können sich in so einem Sprachraum isolierte Inseln bilden, in dem sich lokale Besonderheiten und Abweichungen ergeben, die sich (vor allem dort, wo der Austausch zwischen den Regionen aus verschiedensten historischen Gründen nicht stattfindet) auch durchaus lange halten. Sind diese isolierten Inseln groß genug, können solche regionalen Varianten auch in die Standardsprache eingehen (und es auch in den Duden schaffen).

Beispiele:

- Der/das Teil (Bedeutungsunterschied im Standardsprachgebrauch, in
  Zusammensetzungen ohne nachvollziebare Bedeutungsänderung [der/das Körperteil])
- Der/das Schild (Bedeutungsunterschied, im oberdeutschen Sprachraum
  wohl immer "das")
- Der/das Pfand (hier scheint sich ein Bedeutungsunterschied herauszubilden - "der Flaschenpfand")
- Die/das Brezel ([n] im österreichischen Hochdeutsch)
- Das/die Schorle ([n] im gesamten oberdeutschen Sprachraum)
- Der/das Dotter
- der/die Abscheu
- der/die Fussel

Alle diese Wörter scheinen mir weder Fremd- noch Lehnwörter zu sein. Manche der Abweichungen sind so weit verbreitet, dass sie es auch in den Duden geschafft haben, und natürlich macht dieses Phänomen auch vor "Ge-"-Wörtern nicht halt.

Comment: Zu *»Schorle«* im oberdeutschen Sprachraum, zu dem ja auch Österreich gehört: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22602/differences-between-types-of-schorle/22605#22605

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "das Schorle" ist in Vorarlberg meiner Erfahrung nach durchaus gängig.

Comment: Vorarlberg gehört zwar politisch zu Österreich, liegt sprachlich aber auf einem anderen Kontinent. Westlich vom Arlberg (also nur in Vorarlberg) werden alemannische Dialekte gesprochen, östlich davon (in allen anderen Bundesländern) aber bayrische Dialekte. Die Sprache der Vorarlberger hat wesentlich mehr Ähnlichkeit mit schwäbischen und schweizerischen Dialekten als mit dem, was sonst in Österreich gesprochen wird.