# Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera

Tags: gender

In einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49378/deutsche-substantive-mit-mehreren-genus-keine-fremdw%C3%B6rter#comment120340_49381) zu einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49378/deutsche-substantive-mit-mehreren-genus-keine-fremdw%C3%B6rter) wurde völlig richtig behauptet:

> Es ist schwer, nach Nomen mit mehreren Genera zu suchen.

Eine Liste mit solchen Wörtern würde die Suche erheblich erleichtern, und aus diesem Grund schlage ich vor, dass wir alle gemeinsam hier eine solche Liste erstellen.

Ich mache den Anfang, und poste als Antwort auf meine Frage eine Liste, die dann jeder editieren und ergänzen kann und soll.

Ich bitte um Einhaltung folgender Regeln:

1. Neue Einträge bitte dort eintragen, wo sie gemäß Alphabet hingehören.
2. Bitte nur standarddeutsche Ausdrücke in die Liste eintragen, bitte keine Dialektwörter. Dabei ist aber natürlich zu beachten, dass es mehrere gültige und zum Teil einander widersprechende Standards gibt. Das beutet unter anderem, dass schweizerisches Deutsch erlaubt ist (weil es eine deutsche Standardsprache ist, in der man u.a. auch Gesetzestexte schriebt), Schweizerdeutsch aber nicht (weil das eine Gruppe von Dialekten ist). Im Zweifelsfall ist die Eintragung erlaubt, wenn in der Erläuterung darauf eingegangen wird.
3. Wenn sich bei gleichem Wortstamm die Endung mit dem Geschlecht ändert (*»die Socke - der Socken«*), sind bitte beide Formen anzugeben, ansonsten nur die bestimmten Artikel und nur einmal das Substantiv (*»der/das Bund«*).
4. Bitte in der jeweils ersten Zeile nur das Substantiv mit seinen Artikeln anführen, und diese Zeile fett hervorheben. Darunter kann man in nicht-fetter Schrift Erläuterungen schreiben, um auf regionale Besonderheiten, Bedeutungsunterschiede und ähnliches einzugehen.
5. Wenn man Fehler, unvollständige Angaben oder falsche Formatierungen findet, ist das bitte nicht in Kommentaren zu thematisieren, sondern gleich in der Liste auszubessern. Es ist erwünscht, dass jeder die Antwort editiert und verbessert.

<sup>Ein Tipp zur Formatierung:</sup>
<sub>Wenn man am Ende einer Zeile zwei Leerzeichen setzt, bewirkt das einen Zeilenumbruch. (Ohne diese zwei Leerzeichen wirkt sich ein Umbruch im Edit-Fenster nicht im fertigen Text aus.)</sub>

Comment: Ich mache mal einen Wiki-Lock. Wenn ihr irgendwann mal eine andere Ordnung mit TOC und mehreren, thematisch sortierten Antworten einrichten möchtet, können wir nach einem Flag den Lock auch wieder aufheben.

Answer (score 5):

- **die/der Ausschank**
  der Verkauf von meist alkoholischen Getränken in Gaststätten
  die Ausschank: In Österreich (auch CH)
  der Ausschank: überall sonst
- **das/die Baguette**
  französisches Weißbrot
  das Baguette: häufig
  die Baguette: selten
- **der/das Bauer** (Vogelbauer)
  Vogelkäfig
  das Bauer: selten(er)
  der Bauer: häufig
  Daneben gibt es noch den *Bauer*, der das Feld bestellt, das scheint aber eher ein anderes Wort zu sein.
- **der/das Blackout**
  vorübergehender Stromausfall, kurzer Zeitraum an den man keine Erinnerung hat, zeitlich begrenzter Zustand verminderter geistiger Funktionalität
  Beide Varianten sind ungefähr gleich häufig, regional gleich verteilt und haben dieselbe Bedeutung.
- **der/das Blog**
  elektronisches Tagebuch, (binäres Logbuch), elektronische Kolumne
  Laut Bastian Sick ist *das Blog* die häufigere Variante, ich (Hubert Schölnast) beobachte in Österreich aber das Gegenteil.
- **der/das Bonbon**
  Hauptsächlich aus festem Zucker bestehende Süßigkeit, die man im Mund lutscht
  der Bonbon: In Deutschland und der Schweiz
  das Bonbon: überall, aber in Österreich die einzige Form
- **der/die Bossanova**
  ein Tanz
  die Bossanova: fachsprachlich
  der Bossanova: standardsprachlich
  (*von port. "Bossa nova", "neue Welle"*)
- **die/das Brezel - die Brezn**
  zur typischen Form verflochtenes Laugengebäck, auch die Form selbst
  die Brezel: In Deutschland (standardsprachlich auch in Bayern)
  das Brezel: In Österreich (auch CH)
  die Brezn: Umgangssprachlich in Bayern. In Österreich umgangssprachlich auch: »eine Brezn reißen« = spektakulär stürzen, dabei aber keine dauerhaften schweren Schäden erleiden (*Der Toni hat bei der Abfahrt eine ordentliche Brezn gerissen, aber er ist gleich wieder aufgestanden und weitergefahren.*)
- **der/die Brosame(n)**
  Krümel
  der Brosamen
  die Brosame
- **der/das Brösel**
  Krümel
  das Brösel: In Österreich und Bayern
  der Brösel: überall sonst
- **das/die Cola**
  koffeinhaltiges Erfrischungsgetränk
  das Cola: In Österreich, der Schweiz und Teilen Bayerns
  die Cola: überall sonst; bei jungen Sprechern auch dort, wo die sächliche Form verbreitet ist
- **der/das Dschungel**
- **der/die/das Eck(e/en)**
  Winkel, Kante
  die Ecke: Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum
  das Eck: Oberdeutsch und in Zusammensetzungen wie *Dreieck, Viereck*
  der Ecken: Nebenform in der Schweiz, insb. in der Redewendung «einen Ecken abhaben», aber auch sonst (Beispiele: «Auf der einen der beiden neuen Visualisierungen haben die SBB bereits einen Ecken des künftigen Uni-Campus vorweggenommen», [bz – Zeitung für die Region Basel](https://www.bzbasel.ch/basel/baselland/so-konnte-das-neue-sbb-hochhaus-in-liestal-aussehen-ld.1292218). «Als neuer Co-Partner des ZFF hat das Zürcher Warenhaus Jelmoli einen Ecken in der 2. Etage der Damenabteilung zu einer Styling-Lounge umfunktioniert», [NZZ Bellevue](https://bellevue.nzz.ch/mode-beauty/zff-co-partner-jelmoli-errichtet-eine-styling-lounge-in-zuerich-ld.1644272)).
- **die/das E-Mail**
  elektronische Post
  das E-Mail: In Österreich und der Schweiz
  die E-Mail: Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (auch Ö und CH)
- **der/das Event**
  Ereignis, Veranstaltung
  Beide Genera sind gleichbedeutend und werden annähernd gleich häufig und regional gleich verteilt verwendet
- **der/die Fahne(n)**
  die Fahne: überall
  der Fahnen: Nebenform in der Schweiz (Beispiel: «Zu sehen sind auf dem einen Fahnen zwei Hände unter Wasser», [St. Galler Tagblatt](https://www.tagblatt.ch/ostschweiz/appenzellerland/neue-fahnen-zieren-oberhelfenschwil-ld.523259))
- **das/die Fanta**
  Markenname für ein Erfrischungsgetränk
  das Fanta: In Österreich, der Schweiz und Teilen Bayerns
  die Fanta: überall sonst; bei jungen Sprechern auch dort, wo die sächliche Form verbreitet ist
- **der/das Filter**
  das Filter: fachsprachlich, und standardsprachlich in Österreich
  der Filter: standardsprachlich überall (auch in Ö)
- **die/das Geschwulst**
  Schwellung in lebendem Gewebe als Folge einer Erkrankung oder Verletzung
  Beide Genera sind gleichbedeutend und werden annähernd gleich häufig und regional gleich verteilt verwendet.
- **der/das Gokart/Kart**
  kleines einsitziges Sportfahrzeug
  das Gokart/Kart: in Österreich
  der Gokart/Kart: überall (auch in Ö)
- **der/das Gummi**
  der Gummi: In Österreich immer, in der Schweiz meistens (der Kaugummi; der Radiergummi; der Gummi den man als Kondom benutzt; der Gummi aus dem man Autoreifen macht; der Gummi den man als Ring oder Band zum Verschließen von Sackerln (in D: Tüten) verwendet)
  das Gummi: In Deutschland meist sächlich, aber trotzdem meist: der Kaugummi
- **der/die/das Joghurt**
  Milchprodukt
  das Joghurt: In Österreich (auch CH)
  der Joghurt: überall sonst
  die Joghurt: gibt es laut Duden auch
- **das/der Keks**
  kleine süße brüchige Teigfladen
  das Keks: In Österreich
  der Keks: überall sonst
- **der/die Krake**
  zu den Tintenfischen gehörender Kopffüßer
  Fachsprachlich nur männlich (der Krake)
  Umgangssprachlich auch weiblich (die Krake)
  Die Form *»der Kraken«* existiert auch, wird aber nicht als standardsprachlich angesehen und wird nur wenig verwendet.
- **der/das Liter**
  Volumseinheit
  das Liter: nach DIN 1301-1:2002-10 (seit 2010 nicht mehr gültig). Im Alltag überall, außer in der Schweiz
  der Liter: nach DIN 1301-1:2010-10. Im Alltag in der Schweiz die einzige Variante
- **der/das Meteor**
  Leuchterscheinung der Sternschnuppen, wenn sie in der Atmosphäre verglühen
  der Meteor: standardsprachlich
  das Meteor: selten, fachsprachlich
- **der/das Meter**
  Längenmaß
  das Meter: nach DIN 1301-1:2002-10 (seit 2010 nicht mehr gültig), in der Alltagssprache weniger häufig
  der Meter: nach DIN 1301-1:2010-10, häufig in der Alltagssprache
  Das Messgerät (Smart Meter, Thermometer) ist immer sächlich
- **das/die Omelett(e)**
  in Deutschland und Österreich: eher das Omelett
  in der Schweiz: eher die Omelette
- **der/das Puff**
  Bordell, Laufhaus
  das Puff: In Österreich und Bayern (auch CH)
  der Puff: überall sonst
  kleine Explosion, leichter Schlag: überall männlich (*Der Puff tat nicht weh.*)
  Anschwellung auf einem Chromosom: überall männlich (*Einen besonders großen Puff bezeichnet man als Balbiani-Ring*)
  Brettspiel: überall sächlich (*Das Puff ist ein Vorgänger des Backgammon.*)
- **die/der Schneid**
  Mut, Draufgängertum
  die Schneid: In Österreich und Bayern
  der Schneid: überall sonst
- **die/das Schorle**
  Mixgetränk aus Saft/Wein und Mineralwasser
  das Schorle: Süddeutschland
  die Schorle: Norddeutschland
  (In Österreich gar nicht in Verwendung, stattdessen: *der Gespritzte* oder *der Spritzer*)
- **das/der Service**
  Dienstleistung (Aussprache: [ˈsœːɐ̯vɪs])
  das Service: In Österreich
  der Service: Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (auch Ö)
  Das mehrteilige Essgeschirr (Aussprache [zɛʁˈviːs]) ist überall sächlich
- **das/der Sieb**
  Gerät mit durchlöchertem Boden
  das Sieb: standardsprachlich
  der Sieb: selten
- **der/das Spray**
  kleiner Flüssigkeitsbehälter mit einer Vorrichtung, um seinen Inhalt zu zerstäuben, aber auch die aus dem Behälter austretende zerstäubte Flüssigkeit
  der Spray: In Österreich
  das Spray: überall sonst
- **die/das Tram**
  Straßenbahn
  das Tram: In der Schweiz
  die Tram: überall sonst
- **der/die Tsunami**
  wobei **der** wohl vorherrscht.
- **der/die Zwiebel**
  unter der Erde wachsende Pflanzenknolle
  der Zwiebel: In Österreich, vorwiegend bei älteren Sprechern
  die Zwiebel: Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (auch in Ö, dort vor allem bei jüngeren Sprechern)

### Zweifelsfälle

Hierher verschoben alle Einträge, von denen ich (tofro) der Ansicht bin, dass es sich nicht um ein Wort mit zwei verschiedenen Genera, sondern um Worte mit unterschiedlichen Genera und Bedeutungen handelt (z.B. der/die/das Band).

- **die/der Abwasch**
  die Abwasch: das Spülbecken (in dieser Bedeutung nur in Österreich)
  der Abwasch: Der Vorgang des Geschirrspülens: überall männlich (auch in Ö)
  In Österreich möglich: *Das Geschirr wartet in der Abwasch auf den Abwasch.*
- **der/die/das Band**
  der Band: ein einzelnes Buch, das zu einem umfassenderen Druckwerk gehört
  die Band (englische Aussprache): Musikgruppe, Indianerstamm
  das Band: Stoffstreifen, Bindegewebsstrang, Ornament, Stückmaß, beweglicher Beschlag (z.B. an Türen und Fenstern), in der Mathematik eine idempotente Halbgruppe
- **der/die BMW** (und ähnliche Fälle)
  der BMW: Auto des Herstellers Bayerische Motoren Werke AG
  die BMW: Motorrad des Herstellers Bayerische Motoren Werke AG
- **der/das Bund**
  der Bund: Vereinigung oder Zusammenschluss von Personen, Personengruppen oder Staaten mit gemeinsamen Interessen, z.B. Deutscher Olympischer Sportbund; oberer Rand von Hose oder Rock
  das Bund: eine Menge Zusammengebundenes, z.B. Stroh oder Gemüse
- **der/die* Kiefer**
  der Kiefer: bewegliche Knochenpartie im Mundbereich von Menschen und Tieren
  die Kiefer: ein Nadelbaum
- **die/der Post**
  die Post: öffentliche Einrichtung zur Beförderung besonders von Brief-, Paket- und Geldsendungen (das Postamt) oder die Postsendung selbst
  der Post: Synonym von *Posting*, also einem Beitrag in einem Forum, Blog oder sozialen Netzwerk, das fälschlicherweise aus dem englischen Verb *to post* statt aus dem Substantiv *the posting* hervorgegangen ist
- **der/das Teil**
  der Teil: etwas, das zu etwas größerem gehört (der Erdteil, der Stadtteil, der Bestandteil)
  das Teil: etwas, das lose ist, ohne zu etwas größerem zu gehören (das Oberteil, das Einzelteil)
- **die/der Wartburg**
  die Wartburg: Name verschiedener Bauwerke wie die Burg oberhalb Eisenach in Thüringen oder das ehemalige Gemeinde- und Funkhaus in Saarbrücken-St. Johann
  der Wartburg: ein zwischen 1956 bis 1991 in Eisenach produziertes Mittelklasse-Automobil

### to do

Anerkenntnis
Dingsbums
Gehalt
Kommentar
Korpus
Laster
Nutella
Orange
Pfand
Plastik
Puder
Python
Paprika
Rumba
Samba
Schild
See
Tau
Triangel
Verdienst
Virus
Wehr
Zigarillo
das Tunell - der Tunnel

Comment: *der Bonbon* – in Norddeutschland unüblich. Vielleicht irgendwo nördlich Hamburg.

Comment: *den Zwiebel* halte ich für mundartlich (auch in Österreich). Und ich denke, das ist die Hauptkrux bei dieser Liste, nämlich mundartliche und hochsprachliche Verwendung klar zu trennen. Damit tun sich nämlich auch die Wörterbücher sehr schwer.

Comment: @Janka: Im Gegenteil. Ich bin Brandenburger und meine Eltern und Großeltern kamen aus Mecklenburg-Vorpommern. Ich kannte bis in die Neunziger einzig und allein die Form _der Bonbon_, und zwar mit Betonung auf dem ersten O. Das es die Variante _das Bonbon_, mit Betonung auf dem zweiten O, überhaupt gibt, haben wir erst nach der Wende durch "Fernsehwerbung" erfahren. Ich weiß noch, dass wir uns gewundert haben, warum "die im Westen" so komisch sprechen.

Comment: Gehört Abwasch wirklich in die Liste, wenn bei unterschiedlichen Genera unterschiedliche Dinge gemeint sind?

Comment: @Philipp: Ja. Auch der/das Schild und der/das Bund (beides noch zu ergänzen) gehören meiner Meinung nach in die Liste.

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe mich dabei an der Alltagssprache in meinem persönlichem Umfeld und an Wiktionary orientiert: [die/der Zwiebel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zwiebel). Bestätigt hat mich auch die Zeile *»der Zwiebel – die Zwiebel (findet man sogar im Supermarkt auf dem Preisschild)«* im [Wikipedia-Artikel über österreichisches Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Deutsch)

Comment: Das Zwiebel-Beispiel steht bei Wikipedia in genau dem Absatz, der sich mit der unklaren Trennung zwischen Dialekt und Hochsprache beschäftigt. Es wäre mir lieber, wenn wir die Zugehörigkeit zur Hochsprache an einem Wörterbucheintrag festmachen könnten, anstatt an einem Preisschild im Supermarkt...

Comment: @tofro: Ist [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zwiebel) kein Wörterbuch?

Comment: Das "früher" und "teilweise", das dort steht, hast du ja schön wegzitiert...

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: Dann ist das wohl eher Ostdeutsch, oder Nordostdeutsch.

Comment: Falls es interessiert, *die/das Bong*, weder noch Hochschprache, es handelt sich um eine bei Cannabiskonsumenten beliebte Art Wasserpfeife.

Comment: @vectory: Warum soll »Bong« nicht zur Hochsprache gehören? Das Wort steht in [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bong) und im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bong). Einziges Problem: Es steht dort nur in der weiblichen Form. Und ich habe auch noch nie die sächliche Form gehört oder gelesen.

Comment: war wohl eher "der Bong". "stellte den Bong" wird einmal in gbooks gefunden und ein anderes mal in der Websuche. Ferris MC sagte es auch mal. Sicherlich in Analogie zu *der Kassenbon".

Comment: Ich habe mal eine Unterliste "Zweifelsfälle" aufgemacht und Wörter dahin verschoben, bei denen ich mir ziemlich sicher bin, dass es sich um *zwei verschiedene* Wörter mit verschiedenen Genera und Bedeutung handelt.

Comment: *Nutella*, *Dingsbums*,...

Comment: Bei Wörtern aus dem Englischen Sprachraum besteht oft Unsicherheit, und sie werden sächlich importiert aufgrund der falschen Annahme, man müsse das Geschlecht mitimportieren, und "the Laptop" sei also "das Laptop". Die Sprache hat aber einen Sog zum generischen Maskulinum, so dass es früher oder später bei "der Laptop" enden wird - für Laptop ist das Thema auch quasi durch. Aber nach diesem Muster gibt es hunderte Fälle. Der Blog gehört auch in diese Liste - siehe auch BellesLettres, "Der oder das Blog".

Comment: Wieso sind Kommentare zur Frage geschlossen? Ich will dafür plädieren, 2 unterschiedliche Listen zu pflegen, wenn schon, eine mit Wörtern unterschiedlicher Bedeutung, je nach Geschlecht (Kiefer, Rosé), und einer mit gleicher Bedeutung (Blog, Dschungel).

Comment: Zu einigen Einträgen habe ich (Berlin) abweichende Erfahrungen - Ich will aber nicht drübereditieren, daher hier im Kommentar: 1) (Go)kart ist mir ausschließlich als "das" bekannt. 2) Gummi - auch für Radiergummi immer männlich, (Schieß-)gummi zum Zusammenhalten fast immer männlich, das Material selbst eher männlich. *Das* Gummi wird fast automatisch mit Kondom assoziiert. 3) Den Abwasch kenne ich auch als Synonym für das dreckige Geschirr (*in der Küche steht noch jede Menge Abwasch rum*).

Comment: @Janka Mir als (West-)Berliner ist *der* Bonbon wesentlich vertrauter als *das*, letzteres habe ich zwar auch in Kindheit und Jugend bereits gehört, war für mich aber eher Westdeutsch (tendenziell Rheinland, vielleicht auch BaWü).

Comment: Das Thema kam gerade in einer anderen Frage auf ... soll diese Liste nur Wörter abdecken, die bei gleichbleibender Bedeutung unterschiedliche Geschlechter haben können (Joghurt usw.), oder auch die "Zweifelsfälle" (Band, Teil, etc.)?

Comment: @Raketenolli: Das, was tofro als »Zweifelsfälle« tituliert hat, sind in Wahrheit Homonyme. Strenggenommen sind das also keine Wörter die mehrere Genera haben, sondern unterschiedliche Wörter. Da dieser Umstand jedoch nicht immer jedermann ganz klar ist, halte ich es für sinnvoll, auch diese Wörter in der Liste anzuführen.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... auf den ersten Blick ein nettes Unterfangen, das aber eine unsinnige Behauptung wiederholt und sie zu allem Übel auch noch zur Wahrheit erhebt, nämlich: *"Es ist schwer, nach Nomen mit mehreren Genera zu suchen."*

**Man braucht nicht zu suchen**. :-)) Helbig/Buscha. *Dt. Gramm.* z.B. listen solche Nomina auf, zwei Seiten lang, zweispaltig. Andere Grammatiken tun das auch, und selbst die schlichte *Deutsche Grammatik 2* tut es: https://deutschegrammatik20.de/das-substantiv-nomen/numerus-singular-plural/nomen-mit-zwei-artikeln-schwankender-artikelgebrauch/

Wenn die Liste aber schon sein soll, muss auch deutlich werden, dass *die/das Anerkenntnis, der/die Kiefer, der/das Korpus, der/das Schild, der/die See, der/das Tau, der/das Teil, der/das Verdienst, der/das Virus* u.v.a. **nicht** zu den Substantiven gehören, die ...

**Oder einfach mal hier schauen:** https://www.sprachnudel.de/grammatik/morphologie/wortarten/substantiv/der-die-das

Comment: Praktisch alles, was hier in GSE steht, "kann man irgendwo nachschauen". Ich glaube, wir machen den Laden hier besser zu....

Comment: @tofro - Wer einen *amplifier* braucht, entlarvt sich selber. Na ja, du tust, was du für klug hältst. -))

Comment: Die Liste, die wir hier gemeinsam erstellen, hat jetzt schon (inkl. Zweifelsfällen und der To-do-Liste) mehr als 60 Einträge. Der von dir verlinkte Artikel enthält aber nur rund 40 Einträge. Und deine Verweise auf bedrucktes Papier sind wenig hilfreich wenn man im Internet nach solchen Wörtern sucht.

Comment: Der erste und letzte Absatz wären als Kommentare besser platziert. Vorschlag zur Überarbeitung: Die angegebenen Links mit etwas eigenständiger Erläuterung versehen.