# Warum heißt es "das" Kalman-Filter?

Tags: gender, article

In der Fachliteratur über Kalman-Filter wird stets von **das** Kalman-Filter gesprochen, warum?

Müsste es nicht **der** Kalman-Filter heißen, weil es **der** Filter heißt?

*Edit:*
Laut Duden sind beide Varianten möglich, doch warum gibt es beide Schreibweisen?
Und wann wird **das** verwendet und wann **der**?

Comment: Vielleicht interessant anzumerken, dass  "das Filter"  afaik nur fuer Filter in der Signalverarbeitung verwendet wird. Ich habe z.B. noch nie "das Kaffeefilter" oder "das Wasserfilter" gehoert. Ich weiss nicht, ob das z.B. in Oesterreich anders ist?

Comment: "Warum-Fragen" sind leider im Umfeld "Sprache" ziemlich langweilig, weil die Antwort darauf meistens "weil die Leute eben so reden" ist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nach vielen Diskussionen antworte ich nun selbst auf meine Frage um das Thema abzuschließen. Meine Antwort ziehlt dabei spezifisch auf die Frage ob der oder das **Kalman-Filter** ab, für die allgemeine Frage ob das oder der **Filter** verweise ich auf die anderen Antworten!

---

**Das oder Der Kalman-Filter:**
In der Fachliteratur aus dem Technischen Bereich wird sehr oft von **das** Kalman-Filter gesprochen.
In jedem anderen Anwendungsbereich ist **der** Kalman-Filter deutlich üblicher.
Der Grund dafür, dass es überhaupt zwei Schreibweisen gibt, liegt in der Wortgeschichte des Wortes "Filter" selbst ([Vgl. Wikipedia](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Filter)).

---

**Richtige Schreibweise:**
Ich habe mich durch sehr viele Bücher, Wissenschaftstexte usw. gearbeitet.
In der Literatur werden die Schreibweisen **Kalman-Filter** und **Kalman Filter** verwendet.
Um absolut konform mit den Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung zu sein, sollte die Schreibweise **Kalman-Filter** verwendet werden.

Praktisch nie hingegen wurde **Kalmanfilter** verwendet!
Vermutlich deshalb, weil es sich dabei um ein eingedeutschtes englisches Wort handelt.

---

**Fazit:**
Im allgemeinen ist **der** Kalman-Filter üblicher.
Es sei denn man schreibt z.B. eine Bachelorarbeit im Technischen Bereich dann sollte **das** Kalman-Filter verwendet werden. Da es so in den meisten Arbeiten gemacht wird.

Quellen:
[1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman-Filter)
[2](https://www.uni-koblenz-landau.de/de/koblenz/fb4/ist/AGZoebel/Lehre/ss2012/seminar/jBeschorner)
[3](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-8348-9190-7_38)
[4](https://www.ei.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/media/ei/lehrmaterialien/120/a896a6a0b135530a8a00b094fa631b2ea0e1c95d/KalmanFolien.pdf)
[5](https://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/%7Eubicomp/projekte/master06-07/schetler/report.pdf)
...

Comment: Wie schon oben erwähnt: Btte die amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln für Zusammensetzungen lesen "Kalman Filter" ist ein sog. "Deppenleerzeichen" und ganz einfach falsch (vielleicht auch ein Anglizismus) - auch wenn du viele Beispiele dafür findest.

Comment: @tofro Bitte meinen Kommentar von oben lesen, bin nicht deiner Meinung und werde es genau so lassen. Begründung siehe oben! Dass es mit "-" besser aussieht stell ich dabei nicht in Frage. Wohl aber dass bekannte Mathematiker und Verlage für Fachliteratur es wissen sollten.

Comment: Bitte lies die Links zum "Deppenleerzeichen" und zu den Regeln des Rechtschreibrats (https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6152). Und dann überlege dir dein Statement nochmal.

Comment: @tofro Ich habe meiner Antwort nun hinzugefügt dass Kalman-Filter die richtige Schreibweise wäre, hoffe damit hat sich nun ein Kompromiss gefunden.

Comment: Effort appreciated. Allerdings ergibt der Satz "Richtig ist demnach x oder y, obwohl x richtig wäre" jetzt irgendwie keinen rasenden Sinn mehr.

Comment: @tofro Wird gleich noch umgeschrieben wenn ich am PC bin, ist am Smartphone sehr umständlich.

Comment: Wer auch immer die nächste Änderung vornimmt, bitte noch die Schreibwei**s**e korrigieren. Ich kann leider keinen 1-Buchstaben-Edit machen.

Comment: Sry, hab ich übersehen. Jetzt sollte es passen!

Comment: 2 der Links sind verwaist. Ein dritter scheut auch nicht vor "Normal-Bahn" und "Newton'sche Gesetz" zurück - als sprachliche Autorität mehr als fragwürdig. An technischen Fakultäten findet sich allgemein wenig Sprachkompetenz, so dass derartige Publikationen generell nicht als Beleg taugen.

Answer (score 3):

Aus meiner Sicht (Wien, Österreich, sowohl Technik als auch Naturwissenschaften) handelt es sich in erster Linie um Regiolekt-Varianten. Beide Sprachvarianten sind üblich, aber je nach Region und Umfeld.
In Norddeutschland heißt es eher "das Filter", in Wien heißt es meistens "der Filter".
Ich sehe nicht mal einen Grund, dass es fachsprachlich "das Kalman-Filter" heißen müsste, denn das mag vielleicht nur in Literatur eher norddeutsch geprägter Autoren aufscheinen.

Auf der Seite des Instituts für Hochenergiephysik der Österreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften heißt es klar "der Kalman-Filter" mit männlichem Genus, und diesem Institut wird man kaum unterstellen können, nicht ausreichend fachlich-technisch zu sein:
https://www.oeaw.ac.at/hephy/das-institut/news/news-detail/was-sie-schon-immer-ueber-den-kalman-filter-wissen-wollten

Ähnlich regional unterschiedlichen Gebrauch von Genera gibt es mathematisch-technisch zum Beispiel bei

- "Tunnel": Im Norden fast ausschließlich "der Tunnel" mit Betonung auf der ersten Silbe U, im Süden durchaus auch "das Tunnel" mit Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe E (ähnlich wie Skalpell oder Schrapnel). Eine Schreibvariante mit Doppel-L fiel möglicherweise bei der allerersten Rechtschreibnormierung unter den Tisch.
- "Modul": Im Norden mathematisch "das Modul" mit Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe U, im Süden bedeutet diese Aussprache aber ein Bauteil oder Teil eines modularen Systems. Im Süden mathematisch "der Modul" mit Betonung auf der ersten Silbe O (von lat. "modulus") mit Bedeutung als eine bestimmte algebraische Struktur, eine Verallgemeinerung von Vektorräumen.

Mein Eindruck ist, dass es hier eher um den Einfluß niederdeutsch/hochdeutsch geht, und mich würde es nicht wundern, wenn man bei diesen Worten bezüglich Gebrauch auch die typische niederdeutsch/hochdeutsche Sprachgrenze wiederfindet.

Comment: Das Pendant zu "niederdeutsch" ist übrigens nicht "hochdeutsch", sondern "oberdeutsch" (zu dieser Sprachgruppe gehören z.B. Bairisch und Allemannisch).

Answer (score 2):

### Der oder das Filter?

Die Variante *»der Filter«* ist deutlich häufiger anzutreffen als *»das Filter«,* aber der Meinung, dass nur *»der Filter«* richtig wäre, möchte ich mal ein paar Beispiele entgegenstellen:

> Qualität beginnt vor dem Objektiv, und dort wird bekanntlich **das Filter** platziert.
>
> <sup>*https://schneiderkreuznach.com/de/fotooptik/b-w-filter/verguetungen*</sup>

> Ein Farbfilter lässt weitgehend die Teile des Spektrums hindurch, in dessen Farbe wir **das Filter** sehen. Das Licht, das durch **das Filter** hindurchtritt, hat eine Mischfarbe. Da durch **das Filter** ein Teil des Spektrums absorbiert wird, handelt es sich um eine subtraktive Farbmischung.
>
> <sup>*https://www.lernhelfer.de/schuelerlexikon/physik/artikel/farbfilter*</sup>

> Aus Abbildung 1.2 können wir erkennen, dass am Anfang und am Ende des Ausgangssignals **das Filter** »gefüllt« bzw. »geleert« wird.
>
> <sup>*https://ti.tuwien.ac.at/cps/teaching/courses/dspv/files/FIRFilter.pdf*</sup>

> Je nach Applikation muss **das Filter** Strahlung in verschiedenen spektralen Bereichen durchlassen.
>
> <sup>*https://www.infratec.at/downloads/de/sensorik/detektorhandbuch/infratec-detektorhandbuch-fenster-und-filter.pdf*</sup>

> Das filtrierte Wasser verlässt **das Filter** durch einen Filtratüberlauf.
>
> <sup>*http://www.nordic-water.de/produkte/dynasand-filter*</sup>

> Darüber hinaus reduziert **das Filter** andere Stoffe im Wasser.
> **Das Filter** reduziert außerdem Kalkablagerungen in Ihrer Kaffeemaschine.
>
> <sup>*https://www.kaffekapslen.at/brita-maxtra-plus-filter-brita.html*</sup>

> **Das Filter** ist ein oben offener Glasbehälter der ca 6 bis 7 Zentimeter über die Aquariumoberkante reicht.
>
> <sup>*http://www.anton-gabriel.at/filter.htm*</sup>

> **Das Filter** gibt es in zwei unterschiedlichen Bauformen – für Nassaustrag (A-Filter) und für Trockenaustrag (R-Filter).
>
> <sup>*https://www.chemietechnik.de/das-filter-filtriert-und-filtriert-und-filtriert/*</sup>

> Mit der Erfindung wird erreicht, dass bei der Heißwasserbefüllung **das Kaffeefilter** nicht überläuft.
>
> <sup>*https://patents.google.com/patent/DE202013010499U1/de*</sup>

> Die Feinheit des integrierten Luftfilterelementes wird so gewählt, dass **das Luftfilter** mindestens so fein filtert wie der Flüssigkeitskreislauf gefiltert wird.
>
> <sup>*https://www.filter-technik.de/luftfilter/be-und-entlueftungsfilter/*</sup>

> Wusstet ihr schon, dass **das Kaffeefilter** entstand, weil sich Melitta Bentz damit nicht zufrieden geben wollte, dass der Kaffeesatz zwischen den Zähnen knirschte?
>
> <sup>*https://label-love.eu/melitta-filter-von-friesland-porzellan*</sup>

> Bei vielen anderen Maschinen tropft das Wasser nur auf einen Punkt auf **das Kaffeefilter.**
>
> <sup>*https://www.kaffee-netz.de/threads/behmor-brazen-brew-plus-kurz-review.104088/*</sup>

Und nicht zu vergessen natürlich:
http://das-filter.de

---

### Warum?

Warum nicht?

Nein, ernsthaft: Dass Substantive zwei (manchmal sogar drei) verschiedene Geschlechter haben können, ist zwar eine Ausnahme, aber trotzdem keine Seltenheit: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/49434/1487

---

### Wann »der«, wann »das«?

**Der:** Immer und überall.
**Das:** Auch immer und überall, nur nicht so oft.

Generell finde ich, dass es bei elektronischen Filtern, die irgendwelche Frequenzen wegfiltern sollen, die sächliche Variante recht häufig ist, und auch wenn man von optischen Filtern spricht (UV-Filter, Farbfilter), trifft man auch oft auf sächliche Filter.
Bei Filtern, die Schwebstoffe aus Flüssigkeiten oder Gasen filtern sollen, trifft man die sächliche Version schon seltener, vor allem wen man nach Zusammensetzungen (*das Luftfilter, das Kaffeefilter*) sucht.

Zur regionalen Verbreitung kann ich beisteuern, dass in Österreich die sächliche Version nichts ungewöhnliches ist.

Comment: "das Filter" ist, meiner Erfahrung nach, überall im deutschen Sprachraum verbreitet. Es scheint eine Tendenz zu geben, dass *konkrete* Filter, die man anfassen kann ("Kaffeefilter", "Ölfilter", "Luftfilter",...) eher maskulin sind, und solche, die man nicht anfassen kann (oder soll ;) ) (z.B. optische Filter und *abstrakte* Filter in der IT) eher sächlich sind.

Answer (score 0):

Die erste Verwendung von "das Filter", die ich bei einer Suche auf Google Scholar gefunden habe, ist von 1777 in einem medizinischen Buch (Crantz, H. J. N.  Gesundbrunnen der oesterreichischen Monarchie. Joseph Gerold.).

Die meisten Erwaehnungen im 19. Jh scheinen in einem medizinischen oder chemischen Kontext zu sein.

Auf Google Scholar gibt "das Filter" 1740 Treffer zwischen 1800 und 1900 und
"der Filter" 265 Treffer. Zwischen 1900 und 2020 sind es 13300 fuer "das Filter" und 15800 fuer "der Filter". Grob ueberholt "der Filter" "das Filter" irgendwann in den 1980zigern.

Das und der Kalman(-)Filter haben ungefaehr gleich viele Treffer auf Google Scholar.

Answer (score 0):

Nach ein bisschen googeln und dunklen Erinnerungen aus der Mathe-Vorlesung wird "das" für Filter in der Signalverarbeitung und für verwandte mathematische Konzepte (irgendwas mit Faltungen) verwendet.