# Welche Tipps kann ich benutzen, um mich an das richtige Genus eines (unregelmäßigen) Substantives zu erinnern?

Tags: grammatical-case, gender

Mir fallen die Worte schwer, die keine häufige Endung haben, die mit einem gewissen Genus verbunden ist, wie -ung, -mus, sondern welche, die nicht ahnen lassen, welches Genus für sie richtig ist.

Zum Beispiel, Nomen die mich immer verwirren sind: *Lied*, *Film* (ich zweifle immer, ob es *der* or *das* *Lied/Film* ist).

Gibt es vielleicht einen Tipp für mich, um endlich das *das* mit *Lied* zu ver­knüp­fen?

Comment: kleiner tipp: _ich muss immer überlegen, ob es der or das Lied/Film ist_

Comment: Mittwoch war früher feminin, ich fürchte es wird keine sinnvollen Tipps geben

Comment: Es gibt keine Regeln für diese Art Wörter. Die muss man einfach auswendig lernen. Das Lied, der Film, die Musik, das Theater.... die Geschichte, der Song... keinerlei Regeln... nur stupides lernen...

Comment: Kleine Korrektur: *»ich muss zweifeln«* = jemand zwingt mich, zu zweifeln; ich zweifle nicht freiwillig. Aber *»ich zweifle«* = Ich weiß nicht, was richtig oder falsch ist.

Comment: Ich fände es schön, wenn noch ein Nicht-Muttersprachler mit seinen Erfahrungen antworten würde.

Comment: See Language Learning Stack Exchange: [What strategies can I use to learn the gender of irregular nouns?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/402/800) and [Is there a website to practice grammatical gender of nouns in German?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3291/800).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Geschlecht von Nomen zu lernen, bei denen es nicht aufgrund der Endung vorhersagbar ist, wird immer schwierig sein.

Es geht aber nicht nur darum, den bestimmten Artikel und das Nomen zu verknüpfen. Das Geschlecht benötigt man z.B. auch bei der [anaphorischen Kongruenz](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Kongruenz).

Vielleicht könnte darin eine Lernstrategie liegen: Bei den Nomen, deren Geschlecht man sich nicht merken kann, bastelt man sich Beispielsätze, in denen das Geschlecht mehrmals zum Ausdruck kommt.

> Ein traurig**es** Lied, **das** mich berührt. Ich höre **es** gerne.
>
> Ein exzellent**er** Film, **der** mich fasziniert. Ich habe **ihn** schon dreimal gesehen.

Answer (score 3):

Der einzige Tipp, den ich dir geben kann, ist dieser: Mach es wie die Muttersprachler und lerne separat für jedes Substantiv einzeln welches Geschlecht es hat.

Das Geschlecht lässt sich leicht anhand des bestimmten Artikels im Nominativ Singular erkennen. Ich empfehle daher, die Substantive nicht so zu lernen:

> knife = Messer
> fork = Gabel
> spoon = Löffel

sondern immer so:

> knife = **das** Messer
> fork = **die** Gabel
> spoon = **der** Löffel

Warum das die einzige sinnvolle Methode ist, ist auch leicht erklärt: Es gibt ganz einfach keine Regel, die einem erlaubt, vom Substantiv selbst auf dessen Geschlecht zu schließen. Daher gibt es auch eine Vielzahl von Wörtern, die in unterschiedlichen Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums unterschiedliche Geschlechter haben:

> **Cola:**
> in der Schweiz, in Österreich und in Süddeutschland: **das** Cola
> im Rest Deutschlands: **die** Cola

> **Ausschank:**
> in der Schweiz und Deutschland: **der** Ausschank
> in fast ganz Österreich: **die** Ausschank

> **Joghurt:**
> in Österreich: **das** Joghurt
> in Deutschland: **der** Joghurt
> <sub>*(welches Geschlecht dieses Wort in der Schweiz hat, weiß ich leider nicht, ich bitte um Hinweise)*</sub>

Und von diesen Wörtern mit regional wechselndem Geschlecht gibt es eine ganze Menge (Gummi, Teller, Monat, Radio, Keks, Spray, Service, ...)

Dann gibt es auch homonyme Substantive, die mehrere verschiedene Bedeutungen haben, und das Geschlecht mit der Bedeutung ändern:

> **das** Schild: Plakette, Hinweistafel
> **der** Schild: passive Verteidigungswaffe

> **der** Band: einzelnes Buch, das zu einem umfangreichen Werk gehört
> **das** Band: Stoffstreifen

Auch beide Variationsarten in nur einem Wort gibt es:

> **das** Kiefer: Teil des Schädels, in Österreich und im Süden Deutschland
> **der** Kiefer: Teil des Schädels, im Rest Deutschlands
> **die** Kiefer: Nadelbaum

Eine (leider noch immer unvollständige) Liste mit Substativen, die in mehreren Geschlechtern verwendet werden, gibt es hier: [Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/49433/1487)

---

Ich möchte auch darauf hinweisen, dass die wenigen Regeln, die es für Geschlechter von Substantiven gibt, auch viele Ausnahmen haben. So sind beispielsweise nicht alle Wörter, die auf *-ung* enden, weiblich:

> der Dung, der Schwung, der Sprung

Ebenso ist nicht jedes Wort, das auf *-chen* endet, sächlich:

> der Knochen, der Kuchen, der Rachen

---

Auch hinlänglich bekannt sein dürfte, dass nicht alle Bezeichnungen von Personen ein grammatisches Geschlecht haben, das mit dem biologischen Geschlecht der Person übereinstimmt:

> **das** Mädchen: weibliches Kind, weibliche Jugendliche
> **das** Weib: Ursprung des Adjektivs *weiblich,* früher wertneutrales Synonym für *»Frau«,* heute meist mit abwertender Bedeutung verwendet.
> **die** Tunte: Mann, der eine betont weibliche Erscheinung pflegt (*dragqueen*)

Und natürlich einige Bezeichnungen, die für Personen beiderlei Geschlechts gelten:

> **das** Kind: Person, die noch nicht geschlechtsreif ist
> **das** Genie: Person mit herausragenden geistigen Fähigkeiten
> **das** Arschloch: Schimpfwort für eine widerwärtige Person
> **die** Person: geschlechtsneutrale Bezeichnung für einen Menschen
> **der** Mensch: geschlechtsneutrale Bezeichnung für eine Person
> ...

---

Und zu guter Letzt: Das grammatikalische Geschlecht ist eine Eigenschaft des Wortes, nicht der damit bezeichneten Sache. Eine rostige alte Limousine kann mit diesen Substantiven bezeichnet werden:

> **das** Auto: allgemeine Bezeichnung für mehrspurige motorbetriebene Personenfahrzeuge
>
> **die** Karre: Ursprünglich in der Form *»der Karren«* Bezeichnung für ein einfachen Gestell auf Rädern, das man schieben oder hinter sich herziehen konnte, um darauf kleinere Lasten zu transportieren. Heute auch abwertende Bezeichnung für ein Auto in sehr schlechtem Zustand.
>
> **der** Wagen: Ursprünglich selbe Bedeutung wie der Karren. Heute auch Synonym für ein etwas größeres Auto oder auch für einen Wagon, der als Teil eines Zuges auf Schienen fährt.

Comment: ja, sehr ausführlich... Du hast aber "Die Band" vergessen: Eine Gruppe von Musikern ;). Und "Das Gummi" bzw. "Der Gummi" kenne ich beide im selben Sprachraum, aber halt mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen (Kondom vs. Material)

Comment: @TorstenLink: *»Die Band«* habe ich absichtlich nicht erwähnt, weil das ein Fremdwort ist, das anders ausgesprochen wird. Und beim Gummi hängt es wiederum vom Alters des Sprechers ab. Österreicher in meinem Alter (ich bin jetzt 55) sagen immer »der Gummi«, egal ob Kondom, Radiergummi oder Autoreifen. Jüngere Österreicher sagen »das Gummi« wenn sie ein Kondom meinen, und »der Gummi« wenn sie Reifen meinen. Und soweit mir das bekannt ist, sagen viele Deutsche in jedem Fall »das Gummi«. Ich wollte all das nicht in der Antwort erwähnen, weil es auch ohne diese Spezialfälle kompliziert genug ist.

Answer (score 1):

Lied ist ein gutes Stichwort. Hör viele Lieder, und präg Dir für die Wörter eine Zeile ein, etwa "Ein Lied kann eine Brücke sein" - das scheidet hier leider nur das Femininum aus, was offenbar nicht auf Deiner Liste stand.

Aber kurioserweise kann hier ein Film helfen "Spiel mir das Lied vom Tod". Bühnenstücke und Gedichte sowie Redewendungen können auch Gedankenstützen sein.

"Du hast den Farbfilm vergessen, ..." (Nina Hagen) wäre ein Lied, das den Film (m.) markiert.

Beim Finden kann die Googlesuche hilfreich sein, aber sie ist auch belastet mit einer Falle. Das Verfahren wäre, "Der Film" einzugeben, und zu sehen, ob etwas einprägsames, was Du schon kennst, auf das Du aber nicht kamst, auftaucht. Die Falle besteht darin, dass Du ja alle Geschlechter ausprobieren musst, auch "die Film", und Google liefert fleißig Treffer aufgrund von Deppenleerzeichen, also etwa "die film kritik" (richtig: Die Filmkritik) oder "das film fest" (das Filmfest). Stößt man die Suche aber auch an, dann sieht man überwiegend richtige Schreibung.