# Hilfe beim Übersetzen eines Neologismus

Tags: neologism, russian-to-german

Ich bastle wieder an der Übersetzung des Science-Fiction Buchs aus dem Russischen (siehe meine früheren Fragen im Profil) und hänge an einem Neologismus fest.

Das Wort beschreibt den Vertreter einer Kaste in der Gesellschaft einer Alternativ-Erde. Es ist die Kaste von Mönchen, die die gebildete Elite der Gesellschaft bildet. Der Protagonist und seine Mitstreiter bekriegen die Kirche zunächst, schließen mit ihr aber dann Frieden. Die Mönche sind sehr gut ausgebildet und intelligent, im Endeffekt aber dem Protagonisten unterlegen.

Im Original heißt das Wort "церкач" ("zerkatsch") und existiert in keinem Lexikon, ist also ein Neologismus. Dabei bedeutet das stammverwandte Wort "церковь" ("zerkovj") im Deutschen "Kirche"; das ähnlich klingende Wort "циркач" ("zirkatsch"), das sich nur in einem Buchstaben unterscheidet, bedeutet im Deutschen "Zirkusmann".

Obwohl das Wort im Russischen nicht existiert, ist vom Wortlaut her gleich klar, dass es sich um einen Mann der Kirche handelt, auch wenn das Wort etwas befremdlich klingt.

Die Nähe zu "циркач"/"zirkatsch"/"Zirkusmann" kann auch zufällig sein, die Endung "-ач"/"-atsch" gibt es häufiger, wenn ein Adjektiv substantiviert wird.

Eine mögliche Übersetzung wäre "Kirchusmann" (Kombination aus Kirche und Zirkusmann), allerdings ist das Wort länglich (dreisilbig) und ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob vom Wortlaut her gleich klar wird, was damit gemeint sein soll.

Wenn man die Nähe zum Zirkusmann als zufällig versteht, wäre so etwas wie "Kirchler" denkbar. Hier passt der Wortstamm, das Wort ist als männliche Person mit einer Verbindung zur Kirche erkennbar und nur zweisilbig.

Ist eine der Varianten geeignet, und wenn ja, welche? Gibt es eine bessere Variante, die mir nicht eingefallen ist?

Comment: "Kirchler" ist ein männliches Wort, bezeichnet aber deswegen nicht eine männliche Person. Siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/a/65435/266

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mein Vorschlag wäre "Klerist". Das Wort existiert im Deutschen nicht, ist aber so nah am existierenden Wort "Kleriker", dass einem gebildeten Leser klar sein sollte, dass dasselbe gemeint ist. Es erinnert außerdem an andere mit dem Suffix "-ist" gebildete Bezeichnungen für Personengruppen.

Comment: Das ist eine super Idee, danke! Mir kommt gerade, "Kirchler" ist offenbar ein existierender Nachname und fällt damit flach...

Comment: "Kirchler" mag es als Nachname geben, es ist allerdings m.W. ziemlich selten. Daher würde das aus meiner Sicht noch nicht gegen eine Verwendung sprechen. Allerdings hat "Kirchler" nach meinem Empfinden einen leicht pejorativen Unterton, was evtl. nicht erwünscht ist.

Comment: Eigentlich wäre ein solcher Unterton gefühlt gar nicht so verkehrt, der Suffix "-atsch" geht in eine ähnliche Richtung! Und die Nähe zum Zirkusmann ist ja auch nicht gerade respekteinflößend.

Answer (score 1):

In so einem Zirkus gibt es ja ganz unterschiedliches Personal, und ich finde keine Hinweis darauf, was die genannte Person dort macht.

Wenn man aber *Pfarrer* und *Artist* zusammenklebt, käme *Pfarrtist* heraus, was die beiden Bestandteile noch gut erkennen lässt.

Comment: Danke! Ich habe mich mittlerweile für "Kirchler" entschieden, nachdem RHa meinte, die Sache mit dem Nachnamen wäre seiner Einschätzung nach nicht problematisch. Außerdem ist es dem Original, das ja auch aus dem Wortstamm "Kirch" und einem passendes Suffix besteht, am ähnlichsten.