# Why is it "erster Teil"?

Tags: grammatical-case

I'm beginning to read my first book in German (I haven't taken any courses on the language, just Duolingo, but it's not too helpful) and I am wondering why it titles the first part with "erster Teil" instead of "erstes Teil", because I would have said this is in the nominative case and Teil is a neuter word, then "erste" should become "erstes" and not "erster" which I think is the masculine nominative case. What is it I am not understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Teil* has various nuanced meanings, among them "part (of a book)" and "part (of a machine)". Unfortunately, they differ in genus.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Teil) lists e.g.

> **1. Abschnitt, Glied, Stück von einem Ganzen**
>
> Grammatik: Genus Maskulinum
> Beispiele:
>
> - der obere, vordere Teil eines Gegenstandes, Hauses, Schrankes
> - der nördliche Teil des Landes
> - der redaktionelle Teil der Zeitung
> - der erste, zweite Teil des Buches, Dramas, Gedichtes

which is the "part (of a book)" that your question is about, and

> **4. als selbstständig betrachtetes, für sich allein bestehendes Stück eines Ganzen, Einzelstück, Einzelteil**
>
> Schreibung: Teil; Grammatik: Genus Neutrum
> siehe auch Teilchen
> Beispiele:
>
> - ein defektes Teil ausbauen, auswechseln, einsetzen
> - ich habe jedes einzelne Teil in der Hand gehabt

which is the "part (of a machine)" that you learned as being neutrum (*das Teil*).

While this may come across as very nitpicky and unnecessary on the part of the German language, it should become a non-issue with some practice. Native speakers can distinguish those meanings and use the proper genus without thinking about it.

Comment: There is a short list of German nouns with multiple genders depending on the meaning. Another is See (both die and der).

Comment: There is a similar list at https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/liste-deutscher-substantive-mit-mehreren-genera **but** it also lists words that just use different articles depending on who's speaking or writing, but where the meaning does not change (Blackout, Butter, Jogurt, ...).